# Python code to schedule a task and to call it every day at a given time

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I wrote the following code in Python to perform a function at a particular time everyday. But it's showing the error that "_func1 is missing the parameter 'self'", but when I give the parameter, it's giving the error that 'self' is not defined. Any idea how I can fix it?

```
import schedule
import time


def _func1(self):
        print("func1 is running")
        self.wait(150)
        print('running cycle mode')
  
    
def _func2(self):
        print("func2 is running")
        
        print('running cycle mode')
        print("mode 2 running")


schedule.every().day.at("14:00").do(_func1)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @MatthiasL mentioned in his answer, getting rid of self does the trick. The following code sample is working:

```
import time
import schedule


def _func1():
    print("func1 is running")
    time.sleep(150)
    print('running cycle mode')


schedule.every().day.at("11:30").do(_func1)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```